# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RootComponent.prototype')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, native-base

```
---------index.js--------

import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Navigate from './Navigate';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('form1', () => Navigate);

----Navigate.js-----

import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import TabsList from './TabsList';

export const StackTab1 = StackNavigator({
    TabList: { screen: TabsList},
});

export const Navigate =  DrawerNavigator(
    {
       Tab1: { screen : StackTab1 },
       Tab2: { screen : StackTab1 },
       Tab3: { screen : StackTab1 }
    });
```

Whenever I try to run my android simulator, I'm getting that error. All modules are installed, no errors being thrown within my IDE except for the one that's appearing in my simulator.

Picture below of error:
[image]

Comment: Try running in debug mode. Check the value of each object.

Comment: Check this tutorial - https://egghead.io/lessons/developer-tools

Answer (score 6):

You are not importing `Navigate` properly.

Use

```
import { Navigate } from './Navigate';
```

instead of

```
import Navigate from './Navigate';
```

Comment: Thank You, Akshay but I always import files without curly brace and every time it works.

Comment: Can you provide complete code? I will try to debug it.

Comment: Sometimes it's not Navigate but,
`import App from './App';`
instead of
`import {App} from './App';`

Comment: @Nay That is likely to do with some things are  _export_  _default_ which allows for you to import them alone like your example of App, but if  _export_ is only used when the things imported in need to be specified curly braces specify those exported things.