# Undefined is not and object(evaluating 'RootComponent.prototype)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I checked this question [undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RootComponent.prototype')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576741/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-rootcomponent-prototype) for the error but I could not solve it. There is probably one wrong import but I can not  see what is wrong here.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FirstPage from './src/components/FirstPage/firstPage';

import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; 

export default class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return <AppStackNavigator/>;
  }
}
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
    FirstPage: {screen: FirstPage},
    //SecondPage: {screen: SecondPage},

});
```

**Index.js**

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import { App } from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import React from 'react';


AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: Try removing curly braces which is along with App in index.js like `import App from './App';`

Comment: @VikasSingh It works. Thank you so much but what is the deal here, I don't get it.

Comment: check this out :-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import

Comment: @VikasSingh Omg. Thank you so much. I am enlightned.